# What is the difference between jQuery has() and filter() methods?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, query-performance

What is the difference between `$.has('selecor')` and `$.filter('selector')` methods, and which one of them is better?

Both of them seem to perform the same operation, maybe there are some *performance benefits* of using one instead of other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are quite different actually.

[`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) operates on the matched elements:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

[`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) filters based on the **descendants** of the matched elements:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

---

Practical example:

```
<span class="outer">outer span</span>
<div  class="outer">
    outer div<br>
    <span>descendant span</span>
</div>
```

```
$('.outer').filter('span'); //returns the outer span
$('.outer').has('span');    //returns the outer div
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bzsm/1/)